# Query in elasticsearch with multiple ranges on multiple dates

Tags: elasticsearch

The following [range_query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html) returns a result as expected:

```
{"query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "created_at": {
              "gte": "2013-12-09"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But and-ing together several range queries, returns nothing:

```
{"query": {
    "bool":{
      "must": [
        {
          "and": [
            {
              "range": {
                "created_at": {
                  "gte": "2013-12-09"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "happens_on": {
                  "lte": "2013-12-16"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "created_at": {
                  "lte": "2013-12-14"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

What is the correct way to use multiple range_queries on multiple fields?

**EDIT:** Ah, ok, so this is where I use a range_filter as opposed to range_query? This sounded promising, so I re-wrote my query using only a single range filter. Posting all of it here, in case I'm messing up the query someplace else. I'm performing a GET, and everything inside the source key is actually JSON, but I removed the escaped the hyphens for readability:

```
{
  "source": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "and": [
          {
            "term": {
              "restricted": false
            }
          },
          {
            "not": {
              "term": {
                "deleted": true
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "range": {
              "happens_on": {
                "lte": "2013-12-16"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "from": 0,
    "size": 10
  }
}
```

Regrettably, my problem is still the same: I'm not getting any hits.

**EDIT2:** So, going down the alley of ranges inside a must clause like Njal suggested. This gives me a multi-range query like this:

```
{
  "source": {
    "filter": {
      "and": [
        {
          "term": {
            "restricted": false
          }
        },
        {
          "not": {
            "term": {
              "deleted": true
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "from": 0,
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "range": {
              "happens_on": {
                "gte": "2013-12-06"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "range": {
              "created_at": {
                "gte": "2013-12-15"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "range": {
              "happens_on": {
                "lte": "2013-12-17"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "range": {
              "created_at": {
                "lte": "2013-12-17"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "size": 10
  }
}
```

Still no results returned. Am I doing any obvious mistakes here?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Under your `bool` queries' `must` clause there's no need to wrap it in an `and`. There is no `and` query, maybe you were thinking of the [and filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-and-filter.html)?

[Example runnable play](https://www.found.no/play/gist/7986438) as curl commands for convenience:

```
#!/bin/bash

export ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT="http://localhost:9200"

# Create indexes

curl -XPUT "$ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT/play" -d '{
    "settings": {},
    "mappings": {
        "type": {
            "properties": {
                "created_at": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "dateOptionalTime"
                },
                "name": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "happens_on": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "dateOptionalTime"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'


# Index documents
curl -XPOST "$ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT/_bulk?refresh=true" -d '
{"index":{"_index":"play","_type":"type"}}
{"name":"foo","created_at":"2013-12-09T00:00:00.000Z","happens_on":"2013-12-16T00:00:00.000Z"}
{"index":{"_index":"play","_type":"type"}}
{"name":"bar","created_at":"2013-12-08T00:00:00.000Z","happens_on":"2013-12-16T00:00:00.000Z"}
{"index":{"_index":"play","_type":"type"}}
{"name":"bar","created_at":"2013-12-09T00:00:00.000Z","happens_on":"2013-12-17T00:00:00.000Z"}
'

# Do searches

curl -XPOST "$ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT/_search?pretty" -d '
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "range": {
                        "created_at": {
                            "gte": "2013-12-09T00:00:00.000Z"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "range": {
                        "happens_on": {
                            "lte": "2013-12-16T00:00:00.000Z"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
'
```

Comment: Riiiight. So it turned out the reason I Njals suggestion seemingly did not work for me was that my test was messed up. Now test is fixed and solution rocks. Thanks!