# Is there a short form for multi-field range query

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to write **range** queries on multi-field data. However, each field shouldn't be treated independently. For example, I have the following order:

```
(20, 20) > (10, 1) > (9, 9) > (9, 5) > (7, 10) > (5, 20)
```

Questions [Query in elasticsearch with multiple ranges on multiple dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20610999/query-in-elasticsearch-with-multiple-ranges-on-multiple-dates) and [Elasticsearch date range query using two fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48775491/elasticsearch-date-range-query-using-two-fields) are **not related** because in a situation where I want to find all documents **gt** `(7, 10)` I will get only `(20, 20)` and lose all other documents.

For a two-field case, I can write the following query:

```js
# target query
GET /test/_search?pretty
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "range": {
            "field1": {
              "gt": 7
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "field1": 7
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "run": {
                    "field2": 10
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

It already looks clumsy, but becomes impossible when it requires more fields.

**Sort** query has a form to sort such data as I want:

```js
GET /test/_search?pretty
{
    "sort": [
        { "field1": { "order": "desc" }},
        { "field2": { "order": "desc" }}
    ]
}
```

So the questions are:

- Is there a short form of the *target query* that resembles **sort** query?
- If no, is there maybe a better way of implementing it for a bigger number of fields in the document?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Pretty sure you can find your way using [`range` queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html#querying-range-fields) on [`range` fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/range.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, those are not ranges, especially when we talk about the number of dimensions higher than 2